# Error in SQL Server Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 13

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value DSH to datatype int.

Could somebody help me fix it?

```
select 
    C.[ChargeID], PG.[LocationID], R.[ReferringPhysicianID],
    P.[PhysicianID], C.[ChargeSK],
    R.[ReferringPhysicianSK], C.[PhysicianSK], PG.[LocationID],
    PG.[PAGPracticeID]
from 
    ods.dbo.charge C 
inner join 
    ODS.[dbo].[Physician] P on P.[MergeSupportID] = C.[MergeSupportID]
                            and P.[MergeLevel1Code] = C.[MergeLevel1Code]
                            and P.[PhysicianID] = C.[PhysicianID]
inner join 
    ODS.[dbo].[ReferringPhysician] R on R.[MergeSupportID] = C.[MergeSupportID]
                                     and R.[MergeLevel1Code]=C.[MergeLevel1Code]
                                     and R.[ReferringPhysicianID] = C.ReferringPhysicianID
inner join 
    ODS.[dbo].[PhysicianGroup] PG on PG.[MergeLevel1Code] = C.[MergeSupportID]
                                  and PG.[PhysicianID] = C.[PhysicianID]
                                  and PG.[LocationID] = C.[LocationID]
```

Comment: seems that you join fields that one of them holds integer and defined to be int,  and another usually holds integer and sometimes strings and defined as varchar (or char).
If the comment doesn't help, please post your tables schema

Comment: Thank you Liya. I found my problem.I put wrong join at PG.Mergelevel1code for physiciangroup.